# Combining columns into records for WHERE IN()

Tags: sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

First, I am sorry. I do not have control to change how the data is stored, so I have to work with it the way it is.

I have some tables in a Pervasive database that looks like this:

```
Records:
id |  first_name  |  last_name  | address   | phone ....
 1 |  John
 2 |  Bill
 3 |  Jared
 4 |  Dave


Users:
id | parent_id| first_name
 2 |        2 | Bill
 3 |        1 | Jared
 4 |        1 | Dave

Times:
user_id | Date
 4      | 2020-09-29
```

These are medical records, the `User` would be the patient of record, who may be 3 years old, while the `Records` would contain the billing info, but they may or may not be patients.

I need the data from the `Records` table based on the `Times` table, but I have to go through the `Users` table to get the association. The trouble is that what I want is to not just get the exact matching records, but assign them to `family` groups and return the `Records` for all members of that `family`

So in this case, I would be looking at the `Times` table, getting `user_id` 4, which matches to the `Users` table, gives me `Dave` who is in the `family` 1. I now need to find all the `Users` in that `family`, then getting all those records from the `Records` table, along with the record for `John`.

My previous plan was is to flatten the two columns `id` and `parent_id` and only return those that are within a certain time frame.  This is the only way I have figured it out so far:

```
SELECT "parent_id" as ids from  "Users" as u
where u."parent_id" IN(
    SELECT  "parent_id" FROM "Users" where "id" IN(  
        SELECT "user_id"
        FROM Times as a
        WHERE a.Date >=  CURRENT_DATE() - 2
        AND a.Date <=  CURRENT_DATE() + 5
    )
)
UNION ALL

SELECT "id" as ids from  "Users" as u
where u."parent_id" IN(
    SELECT  "parent_id" FROM "Users" where "id" IN(  
        SELECT "user_id"
        FROM Times as a
        WHERE a.Date >=  CURRENT_DATE() - 2
        AND a.Date <=  CURRENT_DATE() + 5
    )
)
```

The trouble is, I need to use it as a filter for another query like this:

```
SELECT id, first_name, last_name 
FROM Records WHERE id 
IN(
   insert query here
)
```

Which would return:

```
Output:
id |  first_name  |  last_name  
 1 |  John        |  Smith
 3 |  Jared       |  Smith
 4 |  Dave        |  Smith
```

What can I do here? Efficiency is important, these tables have hundreds of thousands of records. Because of the `UNION ALL`, I am not able to use what I have in Pervasive.

Comment: can you add your desired output too?

Comment: "to find all the Users in that family..." -- Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @TheImpaler Because there is no `family` association on the `Records` table, I need to get all related ids from the `Users` table before I query the `Records` table. These are medical records, the `User` would be the patient of record, who may be 3 years old, while the `Records` would contain the billing info, but they may or may not be patients.

Comment: "Because of the UNION ALL, I am not able to use what I have in Pervasive." -- What do you mean by that?  What version of Pervasive are you using?

Comment: Version 11. I don't know why it doesn't work, but it throws an error when I try using that query in the `WHERE IN()`. It works when run by itself

Comment: What error?  What are you running it through (PCC, ODBC, etc)?  Did you try the script I posted as an answer?  Does it fail too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created your tables and added some data based on your post and tried your query as posted and it worked.  I don't have enough data to test performance but you should be able to use the Query Plan / Query Plan Viewer to determine if the statement is optimized.  I used both PSQL 11 and Zen 14 (current version of Pervasive PSQL) and got the same (expected) results.  The query I used is:

```
create table "Users" 
(id int,
parent_id int, 
first_name char(100)
);
create table times 
(user_id int, 
"Date" date);

create table records
(id int,
first_name char(100), 
last_name char(100), 
address char(250), 
phone char(13));

insert into records values (1, 'john', 'smith', 'addr1', 'phone');
insert into records values (2, 'Bill', 'smith', 'addr1', 'phone');
insert into records values (3, 'Jared', 'smith', 'addr1', 'phone');
insert into records values (4, 'Dave', 'smith', 'addr1', 'phone');

insert into "Users" values (2,2,'Bill');
insert into "Users" values (3,1,'Jared');
insert into "Users" values (4,1,'Dave');

insert into Times values (4,'2020-09-29');

SELECT id, first_name, last_name 
FROM Records WHERE id 
IN(
   SELECT "parent_id" as ids from  "Users" as u
where u."parent_id" IN(
    SELECT  "parent_id" FROM "Users" where "id" IN(  
        SELECT "user_id"
        FROM Times as a
        WHERE a.Date >=  CURRENT_DATE() - 2
        AND a.Date <=  CURRENT_DATE() + 5
    )
)
UNION ALL

SELECT "id" as ids from  "Users" as u
where u."parent_id" IN(
    SELECT  "parent_id" FROM "Users" where "id" IN(  
        SELECT "user_id"
        FROM Times as a
        WHERE a.Date >=  CURRENT_DATE() - 2
        AND a.Date <=  CURRENT_DATE() + 5
    )
)
)
```

Comment: Amazing, I had tried to do `SELECT * FROM ()` as a test rather than the `WHERE IN()` and that didn't work, but it does when doing the `WHERE IN()`. Thank you.

Comment: To clarify, I was trying to do  `SELECT DISTINCT ids FROM ()` to make sure I didn't have duplicate `ids` for the `WHERE IN()` to have to process.